# How to pass a callback as a function

Tags: angular

I'm trying to pass a callback as a function parameter.

For example:

```
public abc1(doc:any){        
        console.log('abc1');    
    }

    public abc2(model:any){
        console.log('abcd2');    
    }

 xyz.load(id.replace('/', ''), abc1, abc2);
```

Here `abc1` and `abc2` my callback functions and I'm trying to pass these functions in `xyz.load` as 2 and 3 arg.
All are in the same component.

Answer (score 3):

You could define the load method like so:

```
load(id: string, callback1: (doc: any) => void, callback2: (model: any) => void) {
    // do your stuff here
    callback1(theDocument);
    callback2(theModel);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
xyz.load(id.replace('/', ''), abc1, abc2);
```

Comment: what are callback1(theDocument);    callback2(theModel); here?

Comment: `abc1` and `abc2` in your case. `theDocument` and `theModel` are just placeholders since I don't know where those are coming from.